# Optimize MySQL query with range filter on related table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

So I have a `news_news` table (~16k rows), where every `news` can have many `teams` assigned to it (~33k associations).

```
CREATE TABLE `news_news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `body` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `announcement` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `priority` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `embed` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `source_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `news_news_slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `news_news_author_id` (`author_id`),
  KEY `news_news_site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16521 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `news_news_teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `news_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `news_id` (`news_id`,`team_id`),
  KEY `news_news_teams_news_id` (`news_id`),
  KEY `news_news_teams_team_id` (`team_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40393 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to get last 5 news which were tagged from some set of teams;

```
SELECT 
    `news_news`.`id`, `news_news`.`title`, `news_news`.`body`, `news_news`.`embed`,
    `news_news`.`location`, `news_news`.`date`, `news_news`.`priority`, `news_news`.`status`, 
    `news_news`.`slug`, `news_news`.`announcement`, `news_news`.`author_id`, `news_news`.`source_name`, 
    `news_news`.`source_url`, `news_news`.`site_id` 
FROM `news_news` 
INNER JOIN `news_news_teams` ON ( `news_news`.`id` = `news_news_teams`.`news_id` ) 
WHERE (
    `news_news`.`status` = 'P' 
    AND `news_news_teams`.`team_id` IN (17, 18, 21, 27, 28, 31, 32, 34, 44, 51, 53, 
        56, 60, 65, 73, 75, 77, 80, 82, 83, 87, 89, 90, 92, 95, 98, 102, 105, 106,
        110, 112, 116, 117, 120, 124, 127, 128, 130, 134, 138, 141, 146, 147, 152,
        154, 156, 158, 161, 165, 166, 169, 170, 174, 176, 179, 181, 184, 185, 188,
        194, 196, 203, 214, 220, 221, 228, 229, 230, 234, 235, 240, 245, 246, 249,
        250, 251, 252, 257, 258, 260, 264, 266, 272, 273, 275, 276, 279, 280, 281,
        283, 284, 285, 287, 294, 296, 297, 318, 319, 320, 326, 327, 330, 332, 334,
        335, 336, 337, 350, 351, 368, 369, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 383, 390,
        393, 394, 395, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 405, 408, 410, 413, 416, 417, 418,
        421, 425, 426, 427, 431, 434, 439, 440, 441, 443, 448, 451, 452, 453, 454,
        457, 462, 477, 479, 482, 483, 484, 489, 491, 548, 566, 567, 10001792, 10007454))
ORDER BY `news_news`.`date` DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

Here is the explain from that query.

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys                                           | key                     | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news_news_teams | range  | news_id,news_news_teams_news_id,news_news_teams_team_id | news_news_teams_team_id | 4       | NULL                       | 4075 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news_news       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | cs.news_news_teams.news_id |    1 | Using where                                            |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

It took 2+ seconds to be executed, is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: have you tried `index` on `news_news_teams.team_id`?

Comment: How did you generate your list of `team_id` in your `IN` clause?

Comment: @bluto, check the create statements of the `news_news_teams` table, there is an index on `news_news_teams.team_id` already, or I'm missing something? @Octopi `team_ids` are coming from a list of participating teams in an event. E.g. on the event page we want to show news from the teams participated in that event.

Comment: Ok I see. You could stick an index on `news_news`.`date` since you are ordering by it, see if that helps.

Comment: Id probably say thats the way to go since it is using that to find you your five records in your `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: @Octopi adding only an index on `news_news.date` didn't help, the `mysql` still preferred to use `news_news_teams.team_id` together with `news_news.PRIMARY` key, BUT adding one more filter in the query - to get only the news in the last month convince `mysql` to use the `date` index, and things get much better.  I will post a complete answer later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding index on `news_news.date` as @Octopi suggested is a good idea (since we order by that field), but in this case it wasn't enough to convince `mysql` to use the `date` index. The solution that worked for me was to add one more filter in the `WHERE`, telling `mysql` to search only in the `news` added last month. This increase the query speed around 5-7 times, now it executes for about 250ms.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT `news_news`.`id`, `news_news`.`title`, `news_news`.`body`, `news_news`.`embed`, 
        `news_news`.`location`, `news_news`.`date`, `news_news`.`priority`, `news_news`.`status`, 
        `news_news`.`slug`, `news_news`.`announcement`, `news_news`.`author_id`, 
        `news_news`.`source_name`, `news_news`.`source_url`, `news_news`.`site_id` 
FROM `news_news` 
INNER JOIN `news_news_teams` ON ( `news_news`.`id` = `news_news_teams`.`news_id` ) 
WHERE (
    `news_news`.`status` = 'P' 
    AND `news_news`.`date` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND `news_news_teams`.`team_id` IN (17, 18, 21, 27, 28, 31, 32, 34, 44, 51, 53, 56, 60, 
        65, 73, 75, 77, 80, 82, 83, 87, 89, 90, 92, 95, 98, 102, 105, 106, 110, 112, 116, 117, 
        120, 124, 127, 128, 130, 134, 138, 141, 146, 147, 152, 154, 156, 158, 161, 165, 166, 
        169, 170, 174, 176, 179, 181, 184, 185, 188, 194, 196, 203, 214, 220, 221, 228, 229, 
        230, 234, 235, 240, 245, 246, 249, 250, 251, 252, 257, 258, 260, 264, 266, 272, 273, 
        275, 276, 279, 280, 281, 283, 284, 285, 287, 294, 296, 297, 318, 319, 320, 326, 327, 
        330, 332, 334, 335, 336, 337, 350, 351, 368, 369, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 383, 
        390, 393, 394, 395, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 405, 408, 410, 413, 416, 417, 418, 421, 
        425, 426, 427, 431, 434, 439, 440, 441, 443, 448, 451, 452, 453, 454, 457, 462, 477, 
        479, 482, 483, 484, 489, 491, 548, 566, 567, 10001792, 10007454)
) ORDER BY `news_news`.`date` DESC 
LIMIT 5;

//and the explain
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                                           | key            | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news_news       | range | PRIMARY,news_news_date                                  | news_news_date | 3       | NULL            |  190 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news_news_teams | ref   | news_id,news_news_teams_news_id,news_news_teams_team_id | news_id        | 4       | cs.news_news.id |    1 | Using where; Using index; Distinct                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

PS. `DISTINCT` was added in order to exclude duplicate `news`.

Answer (score 0):

Add both of these; it is unclear which is better:

```
INDEX(status, news_id)
INDEX(status, date)
```

On other notes...

This is redundant with the `UNIQUE KEY` and can be dropped:

```
KEY `news_news_teams_news_id` (`news_id`),
```

This is occupying 3 bytes, although I suspect you never use anything but ascii flags (change to `CHARACTER SET ascii`):

```
`status` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```